# Sort products by their product id in the order they were imported

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting

How do you sort the products in the catalog to sort in descending, of the order they were imported. The latest products imported be the first listed on the page / catalog?  I guess the product id is best method to sort by!

Note:
I just need to place the newest products first. MORE IMPORTANT is that they are placed along side each other! As most of the products are one style, but different color blends. So we import them in that order.

My preferred way of doing this would to place it in `local.xml`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In admin area or in front end?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I know that already. When I sort by "Position", It does not sort the products, by the id!  They are are not in order and scattered?

Comment: do you want to show product based on id on category page ?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237513/magento-sort-by-date-added) might be help you

Comment: No, there is no need to show the product id on the catalog page.  I just need to place the newest products first.  MORE IMPORTANT is that they are placed along side each other!   As most the products are one style, but different color blends.  So we import them in that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the product id, use the `created_at` timestamp instead. Unfortunately neither are EAV attributes, so you cannot configure them in the admin panel to be used for sorting.

But it is possible to add sort options via layout XML. The best answer from [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237513/magento-sort-by-date-added) contains the code:

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setAvailableOrders" json="value">
        <value><![CDATA[
                       {"created_at" : "Latest","price":"Price"}
               ]]>
        </value>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setDefaultDirection">
        <dir>desc</dir>
    </action>
</reference>
```

To add the sort option to all categories, add the code in your theme's `layout/local.xml` inside the `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered` handles:

```
<layout>
    ...
    <catalog_category_default>

        HERE

    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered>

        AND HERE

    </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

But you can also add the option only to specific categories, using the "Custom Layout Update" text field in the "Custom Design" tab. Just paste the code from above there.

Comment: Thank you for reply @fschmengler .  When I place the code in "Custom Layout Update" text field in the "Custom Design" tab, it works perfectly.  But when I want to add the sort option to all categories; by placing it in `app/design/frontend/MyTheme/layout/local.xml`, it does NOT.  Why is that?

Comment: I'd say, either a mistake in the local.xml or you did not flush the cache afterwards. Can you update the question with the full local.xml file?

Comment: I placed it in between `<layout version="0.1.0">` and `</layout>` of `local.xml`.  This I flushed all cache as well.  No luck!

Comment: two times, once with `<catalog_category_default>` for non-anchor categories and once with `<catalog_category_layered>` for anchor categories?

Comment: Yes sir in both `<catalog_category_default>` and `<catalog_category_layered>`.

Comment: Here is a stupid question.  How do I place code in a block in Stack Exchange?  I want to copy part of my `local.xml` to the question.

Comment: Are you sure that it was the correct local.xml ? are other changes in the file working? for code blocks in the question indent each line with 4 spaces

Comment: Yes I just added a picture of the code and it's location.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37963/discussion-between-fschmengler-and-user2774042).